# DBPedia local server giving strange results for different queries

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, virtuoso

I am trying to get list of all wikipedia people with as much features as possible for some machine learning problem.

I have setup a local DBPedia server and already increased the limit for various parameters but somehow I am still unable to get the desired results.

The Desired output is a CSV fo following format:

```
<Person1>,<Feature1>,<Feature2>,<Feature3> .......... and so on
<Person2>,<Feature1>,<Feature2>,<Feature3> .......... and so on
<Person3>,<Feature1>,<Feature2>,<Feature3> .......... and so on
 ...and
 ...so
 ...on
```

**Can someone direct me towards the correct way to do that ?**

For Example, When I run this queries, I got the `blank` result:

**QUERY:**

```
 SELECT  ?name ?birthDate WHERE {
   {
      SELECT strafter(str(?person),"http://dbpedia.org/resource/") as ?name,  str(?
   birthDate) as ?birthDate WHERE {
      ?person a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
      ?person dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthDate .

 }
      ORDER BY ASC(?name) 
  }
} 

 OFFSET 100000
 LIMIT 500
```

**RESULT:**
[[name]][[birthDate]]

But When I run this query, I got only `50000` number of rows which is very less

**QUERY:**

```
  SELECT strafter(str(?person),"http://dbpedia.org/resource/") as ?name, str(?birthDate) 
  as ?birthDate, str(?birthName) as ?birthName, strafter(str(?
  occupation),"http://dbpedia.org/resource/") as ?occupation WHERE {
      ?person a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
      ?person dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthDate .
      ?person dbpedia-owl:birthName ?birthName .
      ?person dbpedia-owl:occupation ?occupation .

  }
```

**RESULT:**
   <<50000 rows>>

Strangely, This query seems to work (atleast upto a good number) -

**QUERY:**

```
  select ?s ?p ?o { ?s a dbpedia-owl:Person ; ?p ?o }
```

**RESULT:** 
<< 1051038 rows >>

**My virtuoso.ini file:**

```
[Database]
DatabaseFile                    = /var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso.db
ErrorLogFile                    = /var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso.log
LockFile                        = /var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso.lck
TransactionFile                 = /var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso.trx
xa_persistent_file              = /var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso.pxa
ErrorLogLevel                   = 7
FileExtend                      = 200
;MaxCheckpointRemap             = 2000
MaxCheckpointRemap              = 1362500
Striping                        = 0
TempStorage                     = TempDatabase


[TempDatabase]
DatabaseFile                    = /var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso-temp.db
TransactionFile                 = /var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso-temp.trx
MaxCheckpointRemap              = 2000
Striping                        = 0

[Parameters]
ServerPort                      = 1111
LiteMode                        = 0
DisableUnixSocket               = 1
DisableTcpSocket                = 0
;SSLServerPort                  = 2111
;SSLCertificate                 = cert.pem
;SSLPrivateKey                  = pk.pem
;X509ClientVerify               = 0
;X509ClientVerifyDepth          = 0
;X509ClientVerifyCAFile         = ca.pem
ServerThreads                   = 20
CheckpointInterval              = 60
O_DIRECT                        = 0
CaseMode                        = 2
MaxStaticCursorRows             = 500000000
CheckpointAuditTrail            = 0
AllowOSCalls                    = 0
SchedulerInterval               = 10
DirsAllowed                     = ., /usr/share/virtuoso/vad, /usr/local/data/datasets
ThreadCleanupInterval           = 0
ThreadThreshold                 = 10
ResourcesCleanupInterval        = 0
FreeTextBatchSize               = 100000
SingleCPU                       = 0
VADInstallDir                   = /usr/share/virtuoso/vad/
PrefixResultNames               = 0
RdfFreeTextRulesSize            = 100
IndexTreeMaps                   = 256
MaxMemPoolSize                  = 200000000
PrefixResultNames               = 0
MacSpotlight                    = 0
IndexTreeMaps                   = 64
MaxSortedTopRows                = 100000000
;;


;; Uncomment next two lines if there is 64 GB system memory free
NumberOfBuffers          = 5450000
MaxDirtyBuffers          = 4000000
;;

[HTTPServer]
ServerPort                      = 8890
ServerRoot                      = /var/lib/virtuoso/vsp
ServerThreads                   = 20
DavRoot                         = DAV
EnabledDavVSP                   = 0
HTTPProxyEnabled                = 0
TempASPXDir                     = 0
DefaultMailServer               = localhost:25
ServerThreads                   = 10
MaxKeepAlives                   = 10
KeepAliveTimeout                = 10
MaxCachedProxyConnections       = 10
ProxyConnectionCacheTimeout     = 15
HTTPThreadSize                  = 280000
HttpPrintWarningsInOutput       = 0
Charset                         = UTF-8
;HTTPLogFile                    = logs/http.log

[AutoRepair]
BadParentLinks                  = 0


[Client]
SQL_PREFETCH_ROWS               = 100
SQL_PREFETCH_BYTES              = 16000
SQL_QUERY_TIMEOUT               = 0
SQL_TXN_TIMEOUT                 = 0  
;SQL_NO_CHAR_C_ESCAPE           = 1
;SQL_UTF8_EXECS                 = 0
;SQL_NO_SYSTEM_TABLES           = 0
;SQL_BINARY_TIMESTAMP           = 1
;SQL_ENCRYPTION_ON_PASSWORD     = -1

[VDB]
ArrayOptimization               = 0
NumArrayParameters              = 10
VDBDisconnectTimeout            = 1000
KeepConnectionOnFixedThread     = 0

[Replication]
ServerName                      = db-IP-172-31-24-242
ServerEnable                    = 1
QueueMax                        = 5000000


[Striping]
Segment1                        = 100M, db-seg1-1.db, db-seg1-2.db
Segment2                        = 100M, db-seg2-1.db
;...


[Zero Config]
ServerName                      = virtuoso (IP-172-31-24-242)

[URIQA]
DynamicLocal                    = 0
DefaultHost                     = localhost:8890


[SPARQL]
;ExternalQuerySource            = 1
;ExternalXsltSource             = 1
;DefaultGraph                   = http://localhost:8890/dataspace
;ImmutableGraphs                = http://localhost:8890/dataspace
;ResultSetMaxRows               = 10000
ResultSetMaxRows                = 1000000000
;MaxQueryCostEstimationTime     = 400   ; in seconds
MaxQueryCostEstimationTime      = 4000000000000000      ; in seconds
;MaxQueryExecutionTime          = 60    ; in seconds
MaxQueryExecutionTime           = 600000000000000       ; in seconds
DefaultQuery                    = select distinct ?Concept where {[] a ?Concept} LIMIT 
100
DeferInferenceRulesInit         = 0  ; controls inference rules loading
;PingService                    = http://rpc.pingthesemanticweb.com/
MaxSortedTopRows                = 10000000

[Plugins]
LoadPath                        = /usr/lib/virtuoso/hosting
Load1                           = plain, wikiv
Load2                           = plain, mediawiki
Load3                           = plain, creolewiki
Load4                   = plain, im
```

Please tell me in case I am missing out something trivial but result of these queries does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to isolate what your exact problem is since you are doing a number of completely different queries. If you want to isolate the cause, the best thing to do is to make small changes.

Also: all your queries are syntactically illegal SPARQL, which makes it hard to judge what is going wrong. In particular the way you formulate your 'AS' aliases is incorrect - for one thing they should be enclosed in parentheses, and secondly you should not alias to an already existing variable. For example, rather than something like:

```
str(?birthDate) as ?birthDate
```

you should be doing something like:

```
(str(?birthDate) as ?bd)
```

Apart from that, in your first query, you are setting the offset to a value of 100000. Presumably, you are not getting any answers simply because there are fewer than 100000 results.

In your second query, you are getting 50000 results, which presumably accurately reflects the actual number of people matching your criteria. Again, the query is slightly odd with you trying "re-bind" variables to a new value using the 'AS' aliasing command.

Finally the last query just retrieves all triples about resources of type `Person`. It is not surprising that this result is far larger as you are imposing no further constraints. Each row in your result will be one property-value combination for a particular person.

I would recommend that you have a look at a basic SPARQL tutorial, because I think you may be missing some of the basics. SPARQL takes a bit of getting used to, but once you learn the basics (like what graph pattern matching actually means), you should find it far easier to write your own queries.